# Dynamic edges in Gephi (Java)

Tags: java, graph, gephi

I'm using Gephi to create a network graph of communities over time, by using the timeline.

How can I do this, so that the edges are dynamic? The nodes need to be static and the weight of the edges needs to change over time.

I'm using Gexf4j to produce a .gexf file to import into Gephi.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I would reverse engineer a dynamic gexf file and try to recreate the structure with an XML library + trial and error. I am almost sure that Gexf4j doesn't support dynamic nodes and edges

Comment: @YannisP. but have you ever seen dynamic weight for edges? I'm yet to find an example of this

Comment: Take a look at the [specs](https://gephi.org/gexf/format/dynamics.html) for GEXF 1.2. They have an example of dynamic edges. I bet adding a weight attribute will not be a problem because this is anyhow the way the edge weight is declared. Essentially, what you have to do is to define a separate edge per interval (same endpoints but different weight) and this shouldn't be too difficult. If it works I probably have to upgrade the comment to a full answer :)

Comment: @YannisP. oh I see. The problem with Gexf4j is that if you try to add another edge to them same endpoints, it will throw an exception. I'll try with my own XML based approach.